# How to confirm users's action with (password) confirmation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, express

For example, the site has a webpage where users can buy something.
When the user logged in he can see "buy button".
When the user presses this button the site must show the page where the user should confirm his purchase by entering his password.

If the password is correct then everything is ok and the transaction will happen. But if his password is incorrect user should stay on the page (he can press "buy button" again and try to enter the password)

The "buy button" was just an example but it can be any protected route on the site.

---

So what I would like to get:

I use node.js (express framework) and I will be happy to get some code but it is not necessary. All I need is the idea and mechanisms of how to do it.

Comment: Simply compare the hash of the password that was just sent with the hashed password of the session that is serialized in `req.user["passwordField"]`.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: no-no-no. I want user to enter his password (if he is logged in already). That's because I should refresh user's session or token or what I need. If user's session was stolen and a hacker tries to buy something he needs to know user's password. That's why banks require you to enter a password each transaction (to prevent your session been stolen)